# Apache: How to always return 404s for URLs whose path component starts with "//"

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I configure apache to always return a 404 for URLs whose path component starts with two slashes (i.e. "//")?

We're getting such requests only from bots that don't understand scheme-relative URLs (so when they see a URL like "//somecdn.com/thingy.js" they request "http://oursite.com//somecdn.com/thingy.js"). They get a 404 response, which is fine. The problem is the 404 comes from our Django code, which dutifully then sends us an email saying someone got a 404 and their referrer was our site.

Here's our relevant apache config:

```
DocumentRoot /nowhere

Alias /static/ /our/static/files
Alias /uploads/ /our/uploaded/files

<VirtualHost :*80>

  ServerName oursite.com

  WSGIScriptAlias / /our/wsgi/script

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried inserting `RedirectMatch 404 "^//"` After `DocumentRoot`, but the request still ended up at the WSGI script. Changing the regex to `"^/.*$"` 404'd every request (as I would expect). `"^\/\/"` didn't seem to match anything.

I'm assuming I'm running afoul of some kind of multiple-`/` squashing, but I don't know how to get around it.

This Apache 2.2.22 with mod_wsgi 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: So I don't have to update my apache configs every time we use a scheme-relative URL with a new domainname.

Comment: For the record, I also tried defining a Location, which the Apache docs seem to say would be doable, but I couldn't figure out the right invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RewriteCond on [%{THE_REQUEST}](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> THE_REQUEST
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

Which unlike %{REQUEST_URI} will not have already been decoded or have duplicate slashes folded.

```
# method, space(s), then URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+//
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

Comment: So it _is_ possible =). +1.

Comment: I didn't think of looking for a variable with the unmodified path. I'll try that out when I get a chance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be matching any request. I've added those directives at the root of the config, maybe they need to be within the virtualhost?

Comment: `RewriteEnging on` helps :-).

Comment: Also, @covener , this didn't work for me in the server config, (rewrite log had nothing written to it), but did work in the vhost. Oh well, good enough.